# Same code except for port numbers; one works but the other doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I have an Ubuntu server with Node.js and Nginx installed, and I create a .js file that looks like this:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url === '/' ? 'index.html' : req.url);
    
    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                res.writeHead(404);
                res.end('Not Found');
            }
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });
});

const PORT = 2000;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at ${PORT}/`);
});


const server2 = http.createServer((req, res) => {              
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url === '/' ? 'index2.html' : req.url);
                
        fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                    res.writeHead(404);
                    res.end('Not Found');
                }
            }else{
                res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                res.end(content, 'utf-8');
            }
        });
});

const PORT2 = 2001;

server2.listen(PORT2, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at ${PORT2}`);
});
```

As you can see, the server and server2 are basically the same, except that they listen on different ports and return different HTML. When I enter http://mydomain:2000, it shows the HTML page, but when I enter http://mydomain:2001, it returns a 502 error. The firewall is disabled and both ports are listening. So why is one functioning while the other isn't?

I thought it might have something to do with my Nginx config.

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
server{
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name myservername.com;

        ssl_certificate "my_certificate";
        ssl_certificate_key "my_certificate_key";

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:2000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }
}
```

When I change the proxy_pass port to 2001 and enter https://mydomain, it correctly displays the HTML corresponding to port 2001. However, in this scenario, I am still able to access port 2000 through HTTP. My question is: why can I access port 2000 directly via HTTP in both situations, but only access port 2001 through HTTPS, even though they essentially have the same code?

Comment: Complete side note but...I would be careful using port numbers that low if I were you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up,  I'll be careful about that.

Comment: firewall? port already used? either way, the idea with the reverse proxy is not to use the ports but rather use `myservername.com` (or another domain or subdomain).